# Excel spreadsheet to XML - issue with loop and data

Tags: excel, xml

Firstly, this is my first post in this community, so using the opportunity, I would like to say hello :). I would like to ask for assistance because I am stuck with VBA code for over a week and I don't have freaking clue, how to solve it.

Below, is VBA code to export spreadsheet to XML form. Thing is, I made a loop here which causing repeating data and I cannot find it. Second issue is related to the fact that, macro print only data from first cells, ignoring others. Finally, this spreadsheet has sort of section of particular data and it would be ideally if user have an option to choose what needs to be print.

Will you be able to assist ?

```html
Sub i()
Dim start As Worksheet
Dim cell1 As Range
Dim rng As Range
Dim reci As Worksheet
Dim blas As String
Set reci = Sheets("Input")
Set start = Sheets("start")
Set rng = reci.Range("A2:A" & reci.Cells(reci.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
Open Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Format(Now, "ddmmyy-hhmmss") & "_input.xml" For Output As #1

'Title
Print #1, "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>"
Print #1, "<dpiva version=""05"" xmlns=""http://www.at.gov.pt/schemas/dpiva"">"



Print #1, "<rosto>"
Print #1, "<apuramento>"
Print #1, "<btBensUELiquidadoDeclarante>" & cell1.Offset(0, 1).Value & "</btBensUELiquidadoDeclarante>"
Print #1, "<btBensUETotal>" & cell1.Offset(0, 2).Value & "</btBensUETotal>"
Print #1, "<btImportDeclarante>" & cell1.Offset(0, 3).Value & "</btImportDeclarante>"
Print #1, "<btOperacoesIsentasComDeducao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 4).Value & "</btOperacoesIsentasComDeducao>"
Print #1, "<btOperacoesIsentasSemDeducao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 5).Value & "</btOperacoesIsentasSemDeducao>"
Print #1, "<btServicosUE>" & cell1.Offset(0, 6).Value & "</btServicosUE>"
Print #1, "<btTaxaNormal>" & cell1.Offset(0, 7).Value & "</btTaxaNormal>"
Print #1, "<btTotal>" & cell1.Offset(0, 8).Value & "</btTotal>"
Print #1, "<btTransmissoesUEIsentas>" & cell1.Offset(0, 9).Value & "</btTransmissoesUEIsentas>"
Print #1, "<ivaARecuperar>" & cell1.Offset(0, 10).Value & "</ivaARecuperar>"
Print #1, "<ivaBensUELiquidadoDeclarante>" & cell1.Offset(0, 11).Value & "</ivaBensUELiquidadoDeclarante>"
Print #1, "<ivaBensUETotal>" & cell1.Offset(0, 12).Value & "</ivaBensUETotal>"
Print #1, "<ivaDedutivelExistenciasTaxaNormal>" & cell1.Offset(0, 13).Value & "</ivaDedutivelExistenciasTaxaNormal>"
Print #1, "<ivaDedutivelImobilizado>" & cell1.Offset(0, 14).Value & "</ivaDedutivelImobilizado>"
Print #1, "<ivaDedutivelOutros>" & cell1.Offset(0, 15).Value & "</ivaDedutivelOutros>"
Print #1, "<ivaDedutivelTotal>" & cell1.Offset(0, 16).Value & "</ivaDedutivelTotal>"
Print #1, "<ivaFavorEstadoTotal>" & cell1.Offset(0, 17).Value & "</ivaFavorEstadoTotal>"
Print #1, "<ivaFavorSujPassivoTotal>" & cell1.Offset(0, 18).Value & "</ivaFavorSujPassivoTotal>"
Print #1, "<ivaImportDeclarante>" & cell1.Offset(0, 19).Value & "</ivaImportDeclarante>"
Print #1, "<ivaServicosUE>" & cell1.Offset(0, 20).Value & "</ivaServicosUE>"
Print #1, "<ivaTaxaNormal>" & cell1.Offset(0, 21).Value & "</ivaTaxaNormal>"
Print #1, "<regularizacoesFavorEstado>" & cell1.Offset(0, 22).Value & "</regularizacoesFavorEstado>"
Print #1, "<regularizacoesFavorSujPassivoNaoComunicadasCobranca>" & cell1.Offset(0, 23).Value & "</regularizacoesFavorSujPassivoNaoComunicadasCobranca>"
Print #1, "<temOperacoesAdquirenteComLiqImposto>" & cell1.Offset(0, 24).Value & "</temOperacoesAdquirenteComLiqImposto>"
Print #1, "<temOperacoesComLiqImposto>" & cell1.Offset(0, 25).Value & "</temOperacoesComLiqImposto>"
Print #1, "<temOperacoesDedutiveis>" & cell1.Offset(0, 26).Value & "</temOperacoesDedutiveis>"
Print #1, "<temOperacoesSemLiqImposto>" & cell1.Offset(0, 27).Value & "</temOperacoesSemLiqImposto>"
Print #1, "</apuramento>"
Print #1, "<desenvolvimento>"
Print #1, "<operacoesPTFeitasPorContribuintesForaUE>" & cell1.Offset(0, 28).Value & "</operacoesPTFeitasPorContribuintesForaUE>"
Print #1, "<totalQuadro06A>" & cell1.Offset(0, 29).Value & "</totalQuadro06A>"
Print #1, "</desenvolvimento>"
Print #1, "<inicio>"
Print #1, "<anoDeclaracao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 30).Value & "</anoDeclaracao>"
Print #1, "<apresentouDeclRecapitulativa>" & cell1.Offset(0, 31).Value & "</apresentouDeclRecapitulativa>"
Print #1, "<localizacaoSede>" & cell1.Offset(0, 32).Value & "</localizacaoSede>"
Print #1, "<nif>" & cell1.Offset(0, 33).Value & "</nif>"
Print #1, "<nifCC>" & cell1.Offset(0, 34).Value & "</nifCC>"
Print #1, "<periodoDeclaracao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 35).Value & "</periodoDeclaracao>"
Print #1, "<prazo>" & cell1.Offset(0, 36).Value & "</prazo>"
Print #1, "<semOperacoes>" & cell1.Offset(0, 37).Value & "</semOperacoes>"
Print #1, "<temAnexoRAcores>" & cell1.Offset(0, 38).Value & "</temAnexoRAcores>"
Print #1, "<temAnexoRContinente>" & cell1.Offset(0, 39).Value & "</temAnexoRContinente>"
Print #1, "<temAnexoRMadeira>" & cell1.Offset(0, 40).Value & "</temAnexoRMadeira>"
Print #1, "</inicio>"
Print #1, "</rosto>"
Print #1, "<anexoCampo40R>"
Print #1, "<regularizacoes>"
Print #1, "<campo40Total>" & cell1.Offset(0, 41).Value & "</campo40Total>"
Print #1, "<certificacoesROC/>"
Print #1, "<lista78ANum2A/>"
Print #1, "<lista78ANum4/>"
Print #1, "<lista78BNum4/>"
Print #1, "<listaNum2E3E6>"
Print #1, "<listaNum2E3E6Item>"
Print #1, "<anoEmissao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 46).Value & "</anoEmissao>"
Print #1, "<artigo>" & cell1.Offset(0, 47).Value & "</artigo>"
Print #1, "<btRegularizacoes>" & cell1.Offset(0, 48).Value & "</btRegularizacoes>"
Print #1, "<ivaRegularizado>" & cell1.Offset(0, 49).Value & "</ivaRegularizado>"
Print #1, "<mesEmissao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 50).Value & "</mesEmissao>"
Print #1, "</listaNum2E3E6Item>"
Print #1, "</listaNum2E3E6>"
Print #1, "<listaNum7Antes2013/>"
Print #1, "<listaNum7Em2013EDepois/>"
Print #1, "<listaNum8BCDE/>"
Print #1, "</regularizacoes>"
Print #1, "</anexoCampo40R>"
Print #1, "<anexoCampo41R>"
Print #1, "<regularizacoes>"
Print #1, "<btOutrasRegularizacoes>" & cell1.Offset(0, 54).Value & "</btOutrasRegularizacoes>"
Print #1, "<campo41Total>" & cell1.Offset(0, 55).Value & "</campo41Total>"
Print #1, "<ivaOutrasRegularizacoes>" & cell1.Offset(0, 56).Value & "</ivaOutrasRegularizacoes>"
Print #1, "<lista78CNum1/>"
Print #1, "<lista78CNum3/>"
Print #1, "<listaNum12/>"
Print #1, "<listaNum3E4E6>"
Print #1, "<listaNum3E4E6Item>"
Print #1, "<artigo>" & cell1.Offset(0, 60).Value & "</artigo>"
Print #1, "<btRegularizacoes>" & cell1.Offset(0, 61).Value & "</btRegularizacoes>"
Print #1, "<ivaRegularizado>" & cell1.Offset(0, 62).Value & "</ivaRegularizado>"
Print #1, "<nif>" & cell1.Offset(0, 63).Value & "</nif>"
Print #1, "</listaNum3E4E6Item>"
Print #1, "<listaNum3E4E6Item>"
Print #1, "<listaNum7/>"
Print #1, "<listaNum8D/>"
Print #1, "</regularizacoes>"
Print #1, "</anexoCampo41R>"
Print #1, "<clientes id=""1907"">"
Print #1, "<relacao>"
Print #1, "<anoDeducao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 67).Value & "</anoDeducao>"
Print #1, "<exportacaoBens>"
Print #1, "<exportacaoBensItem>"
Print #1, "<numeroDeclaracaoExportacao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 68).Value & "</numeroDeclaracaoExportacao>"
Print #1, "<valorEuros>" & cell1.Offset(0, 69).Value & "</valorEuros>"
Print #1, "</exportacaoBens>"
Print #1, "</exportacaoBensItem>"
Print #1, "<operacoesClientesNacionais>"
Print #1, "<operacoesClientesNacionaisItem>"
Print #1, "<nifCliente>" & cell1.Offset(0, 70).Value & "</nifCliente>"
Print #1, "<valorEuros>" & cell1.Offset(0, 71).Value & "</valorEuros>"
Print #1, "</operacoesClientesNacionaisItem>"
Print #1, "</operacoesClientesNacionais>"
Print #1, "<operacoesNoEstrangeiro>" & cell1.Offset(0, 72).Value & "</operacoesNoEstrangeiro>"
Print #1, "<outrasOperacoesIsentasComDireitoDeducao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 73).Value & "</outrasOperacoesIsentasComDireitoDeducao>"
Print #1, "<periodoDeducao>" & cell1.Offset(0, 74).Value & "</periodoDeducao>"
Print #1, "<total>" & cell1.Offset(0, 75).Value & "</total>"
Next
Print #1, "</relacao>"
Print #1, "</clientes>"
Print #1, "</dpiva>"

 
Close #1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the user to select a range using an InputBox Type:=8

```
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range", Type:=8)
```

EDIT - regarding your code

Start loop before the <rosto> tag

```
Print #1, "<dpiva version=""05"" xmlns=""http://www.at.gov.pt/schemas/dpiva"">"
For Each cell1 In rng.Columns(1).Cells
```

Correct the tag following </listaNum3E4E6Item>

```
'Print #1, "<listaNum3E4E6Item>"
Print #1, "</listaNum3E4E6>"
```

Swap these 2 lines

```
'Print #1, "</exportacaoBens>"
'Print #1, "</exportacaoBensItem>"
Print #1, "</exportacaoBensItem>"
Print #1, "</exportacaoBens>"
```

Move next to before </dpiva> tag

```
'Next
Print #1, "</relacao>"
Print #1, "</clientes>"
Next
Print #1, "</dpiva>"
```

Comment: CDP1802  - thank you for the input. I checked your code and seems that it doesn't work. Macro still repeating flow ( 5 times). Any other ideas? Regards !

Comment: @TStudzinski Do you mean the file contains 5 times the number of records it should ? What range in rng are you using ?

Comment: Hi! I am sorry for late response. Finally I managed to kill that loop with simple command therefore I would like to thank you CDP1802 for your tips. Now I am struggling with layout of these xml because I'm not sure why final output looks like string of figures instead of tree?